# Serverless Framework with AWS cognito generates CORS error

Tags: python, cors, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I get this error message from the Angular frontend and I am not authorized to touch my lambda code:

```
`Access to fetch at 'https://testapicd.***.***.com/localization/v1/role' from origin 'https://localization.test.***.***.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
```

I have looked everywhere and there seems to be no bug in my code. My serverless code is

```
  getrole:
    handler: v1/handler_get_role.get_role
    name: get_role
    events:
      - http:
          path: v1/role
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            name: CognitoCSAuthorizer
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            arn: ${file(config.${self:provider.stage}.json):userpoolarn}
```

I have triple-checked all the settings and everything seems correct. Any advice what to do? The functionality works in the dev environment but not when I deploy it to the test environment.

If I try the token directly against the API, then it does not work either (but worked fine in dev). I don't even believe anymore that it is a CORS problem. I think that the jwt token is wrong.

```
def get_role(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*', # Required for CORS support to work
         'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        },
        'body': json.dumps("TEST")
     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have wrestled with this problem for hours (if not days) before and it turned out not only I had to enable cors on the `serverless.yml` file but also add the response headers as attributes in the object you return from your Lambda.

Something like this should do it:

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      product: product
    }),
  };
```

This [article](https://serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/) saved my life back then and I hope it saves yours!

Comment: I don't even believe anymore that it is a CORS problem. I think that the jwt token is wrong.

Comment: I did try it from Postman. It did not work. So we agree it is not a CORS issue then?

Comment: We found the bug...It was the authorizer in API Gateway test environment which was pointing to the dev userpool and not getting updated. We are fixing it now... Thanks for the help. You were right.

Comment: The bug was in serverless.yml where we had set `provider:stage` which was always `dev` and I could correct it to `opt:stage` which will depend on the stage which is either `dev`, `test` or `prod`. Will celebrate this tonite! :-)

Comment: Well deserved! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The [CORS error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is thrown when you are making requests to servers in other domains. Depending on the server you are using to host the angular code there are many ways you can solve this.

You can try [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) google chrome extension to see if you can effectivelly fix the problem by ignoring the CORS errors.

One of the most commons ways to solve this problem is to configure a [proxy server](https://medium.com/netscape/hacking-it-out-when-cors-wont-let-you-be-great-35f6206cc646), but you can also solve it by whitelisting your test domain manipulating the header [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) in your requests.

Answer (score 1):

This line in serverless.yml

`arn: ${file(config.${self:provider.stage}.json):userpoolarn}`

Should have been

`arn: ${file(config.${opt:stage}.json):userpoolarn}`