# Woocommerce webhook to AWS API-Gateway : CORS/Header issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, woocommerce, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send a Woocommerce webhook to AWS API Gateway. When i put in my API Gateway URL on Amazon I get the following error:

```
Error: Delivery URL returned response code: 415
```

I think this is related to headers, there is an option to Create CORS in API-Gateway that I have now done. Which then adds an OPTION method but I still get `undefined` in Cloudwatch

[image]

I created a POST method and used the mapping template below with application/json and the setting `When there are no templates defined (recommended)`

```
{
    "body" : $input.json('$'),
        "headers": {
        #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
        "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if ($foreach.hasNext), #end

        #end
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is a mini Lambda Node function that just outputs a Woocommerce order number to the console and shows in Cloudwatch whether the API passthrough is working.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback, err) => {
    //callback(null, event.meta_data);
    if (err) console.log('JSON Pass Fail');  // an error occurred
    else console.log(event.order_key); // successful response
};
```

If anyone did want to have a go at re-creating this, you can knock up a quick Wordpress install on cPanel and install the Woocommerce Plugin. Setup a dummy product and then just use the Cash on Delivery as a payment method to get your "Order Created" webhooks firing. Only takes 2 minutes.

You can use https://requestbin.com/ or webhook.site to test out webhook outputs.

Can anyone help sorting out the Headers so i can pass a Woocommerce payload to API Gateway?

Comment: have you also enabled CORS on your function? it needs to be present at both API gateway and in your response

Comment: Hi, CORS is enabled. Just wondering whether the header part in the mapping template is needed now that CORS is enabled. Should it just be left as body

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I didn't express myself very well. By "enabling" it in the function I meant adding the response headers, like this `const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      product: product
    }),
  };`

Comment: I don't have that in my actual Lambda function code no. I'll give that a try. A year or so ago, that code above worked. But perhaps AWS have tweaked the CORS setup somewhere.

Comment: All I am looking for is to get the Webhook JSON body data into an event, like I would if if added it to the AWS Lambda test event.

Comment: Many people run into this problem. I'd change your code to Node 8, so you can use async await and get rid of callbacks. It should look like: exports.handler = async (event) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(event)); return { statusCode: 200, headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true, }, body: JSON.stringify(event) }} Please see if it helps. I have answered pretty much the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805730/serverless-framework-with-aws-cognito-generates-cors-error/54806911#54806911